# How to replace bitmap white pixels with red using AForge?

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I know this can be done with `GetPixel/SetPixel`, but that takes too long.

I am trying to accommodate AForge now and would want to know if there is a filter which can do this quickly.

Comment: `GetPixel/SetPixel` will likely be the quickest method for doing this. Perhaps if you posted your code we could help you optimize it so it wouldn't take as long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [EuclideanColorFiltering](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/67fa83b5-dede-8d3a-8d3b-b7a6b9859538.htm) to achieve this:

```
 EuclideanColorFiltering filter = new EuclideanColorFiltering();            
 filter.CenterColor = new AForge.Imaging.RGB(Color.White); //Pure White
 filter.Radius = 0; //Increase this to allow off-whites
 filter.FillColor = new AForge.Imaging.RGB(Color.Red); //Replacement Colour
 filter.ApplyInPlace(image);
```

Comment: A bit of correction to apply the colors: `CenterColor = new AForge.Imaging.RGB(Color.White)`. This filter replaces with red all the colors except the white. I need the white pixels to be replaced with red.

Comment: Ah I see. My apologies! I misread the documentation on EuclideanColorFiltering. If you want to use AForge you could either implement your own filter using unsafe pointer operations on the bitmap for speed, or use System.Drawing.Bitmap.Lockbits(), iterate through the pixel data array, make your changes, and then Marshal.Copy back to the bitmap.

Comment: (Both of those techniques will be many times faster than SetPixel).

Comment: Actually, the code will work if you set `filter.FillOutside = false;`, since this will make it fill in just white, and not all but white.